# jQuery each loop inside of dynamic dom element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am generating a dom element `<div>` using the code below:

**jQuery**

```
$('<div/>', {
    'id': 'myid',
    'html': '<table class="table">'
    + '<tr><th>Heading</th><th>Heading</th><th>Heading</th></tr>'

    +'</table>'
}).appendTo($body);
```

Everything works great. I would like to loop through my data to create the actual table rows, but I'm getting actual output (which makes sense I suppose). Just not sure how to not do that.

For example:

**jQuery**

```
$('<div/>', {
    'id': 'myid',
    'html': '<table class="table">'
    + '<tr><th>Heading</th><th>Heading</th><th>Heading</th></tr>' +
        $.each(data.thing, function(i, val){
         '<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        });                                      
    +'</table>'
}).appendTo($body);
```

But, I am getting this for the result:

**HTML**

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object    
Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Heading Heading Heading
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$.map()` to iterate, and then `join()` to combine the results.

```
$('<div/>', {
    'id': 'myid',
    'html': '<table class="table">'
    + '<tr><th>Heading</th><th>Heading</th><th>Heading</th></tr>' +
        $.map(data.thing, function(i, val){
          return '<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>';
        }).join('');                                      
    +'</table>'
}).appendTo($body);
```

Note that the iteration function has to `return` the string -- just writing the string as a statement doesn't return it.

Comment: This works fantastic. I'll do some testing to check speed if/when things get heavy-duty. But for now, I think the most I'll have is 8 objects to loop over so this should work great. Thank you to everyone for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

`$.each()` returns the object (`data.thing`, here) that it acts on. You're seeing the stringified version of that.

You can't really loop as part of a data definition. Better to do so afterwards:

```
var table = $('<table class="table">' +
                 '<tr><th>Heading</th><th>Heading</th><th>Heading</th></tr>' +
              '</table>');

$.each(data.thing, function(i, val){
  table.append( '<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>' );
});

$('<div>').
  attr('id', 'myid').
  append(table).
  appendTo($body);
```

Example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/dvnKE

Comment: +1 .. Not tying to be nit picky . But I feel appending row to the table on each iteration might hit processing speed as the no of rows keep increasing. instead prefer store in a string and append it after the loop.

Comment: That would depend heavily on the number of rows, and could in fact be problematic in terms of memory usage. Something I'd want to measure before worrying either way.